# Rental lease agreement, what does Provided Further mean?

Tags: contract-law, rental-property

If someone recently purchased a house that has a tenant but would like to rent to a close young family member that recently moved to town. The lease agreement that was inherited from the previous property owner stated that:

> Lessor or Agent may terminate this lease upon 30 days' notice in writing prior to the next rent payment date to the address shown herein; PROVIDED FURTHER, that in the event Lessee terminates this Lease prior to first 12 months from the date this Lease is executed, such termination shall constitute a failure to comply with this Agreement and the Security Deposit shall be forfeited pursuant to the section on Security Deposit.

What does "*PROVIDED FURTHER*" here mean? Does it mean the landlord is allowed to give 30 day notice *conditional* on the tenant not paying rent, or does it mean *in addition to*, such that the landlord can *unconditionally*  give 30 day notice to the tenant to move out, and if the tenant does not pay on time, the security deposit is forfeited?

Comment: Note that the second part refers to termination, not non-payment of rent.

Answer (score 3):

> What does "PROVIDED FURTHER" here mean?

The term keeps two provisions separate, and hence independent of each other (unconditional). The former provision addresses landlord's initiative [to terminate the lease] whereas the latter addresses tenant's initiative. The latter pertains to *early termination of lease* and is not to be confused with tenant's default/non-payment.

If rent is to be paid on the 1st of each month and the landlord wants the tenant to move out by August 13, the landlord needs to give a written notice at least thirty days prior to August 1 because the 1st of August is "*the next rent payment date*". This is regardless of tenant's timely payment of rent.

Tenant's initiative to prematurely terminate the lease forfeits his security deposit regardless of having hitherto/always paid rent on time.